# How to check and return value of state object array and use that to identify which object to take data from

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, semantic-ui

*The Aim:* Use the value of `i.id` from the mapped components when clicked on to search state `ids` and locate the *object* which contains the same `id` value... When this object is found to return/update `id` and `active` values.

Clicking on the dynamic rendered component triggering `onClick` to change value of the current `active: true` to `active: false` and find object with `id` of the clicked component and `this.setState({active:value})` in that object.
Then `if (active === true)` render iframe containing the object's `id` value.

The *state*

```
this.state = {
      ids: [
        {
          id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
          active: true,
        },
        {
          id: "qvOcCQXZVg0",
          active: false,
        },
        {
          id: "YXNC3GKmjgk",
          active: false,
        },
      ],
    };
```

The components rendered for each state

```
{this.state.ids.map((i) => (
                    <Image
                      className="carouselitem"
                      rounded
                      fluid
                      src={
                        "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"
                      }
                      size="small"
                    />
                  ))}
```

I am Really Stumped for what to do

I tried an `if` loop inside a `for ...in...` loop... but gave me nothing but errors when trying to render the page.

Full Code

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Embed, Icon, Image, List } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./Services.css";
import logo from "./images/EIB 3D Logo v25.png";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import MediaQuery from "react-responsive";

export default class Services extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ids: [
        {
          id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
          active: true,
        },
        {
          id: "qvOcCQXZVg0",
          active: false,
        },
        {
          id: "YXNC3GKmjgk",
          active: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  handleClick = (props) => {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="serviceswrap">
        <div className="servicesbdrop">
          <div className="primarywrap">
            <div className="primaryvideo">
              <div className="carousel">
                <div className="slider">
                  {this.state.ids.map((i) => (
                    <Image
                      className="carouselitem"
                      rounded
                      fluid
                      src={
                        "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"
                      }
                      size="small"
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <List size="big" className="servicesList">
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">3D Printing</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Print your design using our 3d-printer.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">CNC Machining</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Print your design using our CNC machienery.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">Personalised Designs</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Design your idea to suite your needs.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">Laser Etching</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Elegant designs etched onto wood.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">Wood Working</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Build custom designed indoor and outdoor wooden signage.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
            </List>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's actually very simple...

```
onClick={() => {
                  this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    ids: prevState.ids.map((ob) =>
                      ob.id !== i.id
                        ? { ...ob, active: false }
                        : { ...ob, active: true }
                    ),
                  }));
                }}
```

this anon function finds the `objects` that have `id!== i.id` and updates their `objects` to `active: false` then updates the `object` with `id === i.id`

Then this *(the next codeblock)*  finds the `object` that has `active: true` and returns its `id: value`

```
firstActiveId = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ids.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.ids[i].active) {
        return this.state.ids[i].id;
      }
    }
  };
```

It is then passed into the element `activevid` where it completes the URL of the `placeholder` and the `id` of the `iframe` which is used to retrieve the youtube url.

```
 <div className="activevid">
          <Embed
            active
            autoplay={true}
            color="white"
            hd={false}
            id={this.firstActiveId(this.state.ids)}
            iframe={{
              allowFullScreen: true,
              style: {
                padding: 0,
              },
            }}
            placeholder={
              "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" +
              this.firstActiveId(this.state.ids) +
              "/hqdefault.jpg"
            }
            source="youtube"
          />
        </div>
```

Here is the full component to see the placements.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Embed, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./Player.css";

export default class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ids: [
        {
          id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
          active: false,
        },
        {
          id: "qvOcCQXZVg0",
          active: true,
        },
        {
          id: "YXNC3GKmjgk",
          active: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  firstActiveId = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ids.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.ids[i].active) {
        return this.state.ids[i].id;
      }
    }
  };

 

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="carouselwrap">
        <div className="activevid">
          <Embed
            active
            autoplay={true}
            color="white"
            hd={false}
            id={this.firstActiveId(this.state.ids)}
            iframe={{
              allowFullScreen: true,
              style: {
                padding: 0,
              },
            }}
            placeholder={
              "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" +
              this.firstActiveId(this.state.ids) +
              "/hqdefault.jpg"
            }
            source="youtube"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="thumbs">
          {this.state.ids.map((i) => (
            <>
              <Image
                className="carouselitem"
                rounded
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    ids: prevState.ids.map((ob) =>
                      ob.id !== i.id
                        ? { ...ob, active: false }
                        : { ...ob, active: true }
                    ),
                  }));
                }}
                src={"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"}
                size="small"
              />
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `button` inside each mapped component as follows.

```
{
  this.state.ids.map((i) => (
    <>
      <Image
        className="carouselitem"
        rounded
        fluid
        src={"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"}
        size="small"
      />
      <button onClick={() => this.changeActiveField(id)}>Change Activation</button>
    </>
  ));
}
```

Then create `changeActiveField` method inside the class component for `active` field change in relevant object.

```
changeActiveField = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    ids: this.state.ids.map((obj) =>
      obj.id === id ? { ...obj, active: false } : obj
    ),
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert this method that you used to create the change active field component into one that uses a standard array rather than state methods. what should I eferr to do learn it?